# How this angle is calculated?

Tags: geometry

[image]

How is the -17 is calculated?

I knew that arccos is the inverse of cosine. So, we have the formula: $\alpha = $arccos$\dfrac{Adjacent}{Hypotenuse}$. But this is not right angle.

Comment: Do you know about [inner products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) or the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another equation which can be used for calculating angles between vectors, which is $$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec a \cdot\vec b}{|\vec a|\times|\vec b|}$$

Here this is what is used. $\vec a \cdot \vec b$ is the scalar product of the two vectors away from the point. In this case, these are $\vec a =(2,-7)$ and $\vec b=(2,3)$, so $\vec a \cdot \vec b=2\cdot2+(-7)\cdot3=4-21=-17$. $|\vec a|=\sqrt{2^2+(-7)^2}=\sqrt{53}$, $|\vec b|=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}=\sqrt{13}$. This is what gives the formula you have.

Answer (score 1):

Here $-17$ is the dot product of the vector $(2,3)$ (which is the vector from $t_4$ to $t_2$) and the vector $(2,-7)$ (which is the vector from $t_4$ to $t_6$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use:
$ \langle u,v\rangle=|u|\cdot |v|\cdot \cos \alpha$

where $\langle u,v\rangle$ is the dot product between the two vectors $u=t_2-t_4=(2,3)^T$ and $v=t_6-t_4=(2,-7)^T$  and $\alpha$ is the angle between these two vectors.